# How to format SAS script with complex proc SQL

Tags: sql, sas, formatting

Today I am being asked to format long SAS script with mainly Proc SQL which are not readable (do not respect simple SQL rules of readability):

- imbricated SQL queries with no indentation
- case is not respected
- etc...

I tried automatic SaS formatter but it do not format Proc SQL. Do you have any ideas ? We have many scripts and the Team is ready to do that manually, it seems prone to error and I am not sure we'll have the same syntax at the end.

Any tips would be welcome!
I can add code snippets if needed but I think that the problem is clear and I am not the first to encounter it.

Comment: FYI, it's not on-topic to ask for code libraries or applications, so can't answer with that - but you can find some SAS linters and such that may help if you look around, if you don't like my solution.

Comment: For overly large or poorly coded SQL, you can use a free online SQL formatter.  Just search one up.  In ugly out pretty

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest ignoring the fact that you're in SAS for the moment, and instead focus on the SQL itself.  Find a language you're comfortable with that has libraries that format code in other languages - Python for example can do this - and then:

1. Open the .sas file as a text file
2. Find "PROC SQL" text and grab from there to the "QUIT" (case insensitive)
3. Pass that inner text to the SQL code formatter
4. Grab the result and insert it back into the text file

Something along those lines is your best bet.  SAS doesn't have anything built-in for this, so you're going to have to go outside here.

Comment: Thanks Joe! If i understand well you suggest to write a script (with Python for example) which detect the PROC SQL and END statement to feed the content to  any sql formatter.  So with the help of such a formatter (have you any sql libraries suggestions ?) i can  automatize the whole process.

Comment: Yes that’s the idea.